# UINavigationBar Large Title doesn't appear when scroll view up

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, scrollview, contentoffset

I have implemented a feature, when you press on a `UITabBar` icon and `viewController1` scrolls up using its `UIScrollView`. It works perfectly, but if I scroll `view` down and stop somewhere, then switch to another `viewController2`, then get back to `viewController1` and press `tabBar` icon - the `viewController1` will scroll up, but `Large Title` will never be showed, and I should press `tabBar` icon one more time to show it:

[image]

The code I use for scroll up the VC1:

```
private var biggestTopSafeAreaInset: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange() {
        super.viewSafeAreaInsetsDidChange()
        self.biggestTopSafeAreaInset = max(view.safeAreaInsets.top, biggestTopSafeAreaInset)
    }
    
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
        if tabBarController.selectedIndex == 0 {
            let navigationVC = viewController as? UINavigationController
            let firstVC = navigationVC?.viewControllers.first as? CurrencyViewController
            guard let scrollView = firstVC?.view.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView else { return }
            
            if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
                scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -view.safeAreaInsets.top, animated: true)
            } else {
                scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -biggestTopSafeAreaInset, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to track `biggestTopSafeAreaInset` in different stages of `VC1` life, but it always has the same number - 196.0. But then why it doesn't scroll till the `Large Title` after viewControllers switch?

Comment: it's more like a apple issue, because it's ok by default and when you change tab it's occurred .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your tableView set contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to never

```
tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
```

in controller update the ui of navigation bar again

```
  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.navigationController?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
        }
       
    }
```

here is the navigation controller

```
class BaseNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
            let scrollAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            scrollAppearance.shadowColor = .white
            scrollAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
            let navigationBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
            navigationBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            navigationBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .white
            navigationBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            UINavigationBar.appearance().backIndicatorImage = UIImage(named: "back-arrow")
            UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navigationBarAppearance
            UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = scrollAppearance
            navigationBar.tintColor = .black
            navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        } else {
            navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 26),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
                NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17),
                NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black
            ]
            navigationBar.tintColor = .black
            navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
            navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
            navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
            navigationBar.barTintColor = .white
        }
        
    }
    
    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .darkContent
    }

    
}
```

here is the Tabbar Controller

```
class TabbarController:UITabBarController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let c1 = C1()
        let c2 = C2()
        let c3 = C3()
        
        c1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named:  "home786"), tag: 0)
        c1.tabBarItem.tag = 0
        let nav1 = BaseNavigationController(rootViewController: c1)
        
        c2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Setting", image: UIImage(named:  "home786"), tag: 0)
        c2.tabBarItem.tag = 1
        let nav2 = BaseNavigationController(rootViewController: c2)
        c2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "User", image: UIImage(named:  "home786"), tag: 0)
        c2.tabBarItem.tag = 2
        let nav3 = BaseNavigationController(rootViewController: c3)
        viewControllers = [nav1,nav2,nav3]
        selectedViewController = nav1
        tabBarController?.viewControllers?.first?.view.backgroundColor = .red
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Zeeshan! Thank you foe the reply! Tried your solution, but didn't work: navigation bar became translucent and tableView was placed underneath it from a screen top...

Comment: I think you have some issue with navigation controller this is how I solved this issue and its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
```

this single line block large title navigation Bar... I don't Know why, but this trick fix momentarily the issue...

Comment: Hi Fabio! Thank you for the answer! Tried your suggestion but no luck, behaviour stayed the same. Strange, but only call to `navigationBar.sizeToFit()` with some delay fix it...

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found out what can fix my problem. If you call this method with a small delay in `tabBarController didSelect` then it will be possible to see a Large Title after switching viewControllers. But I still can't figure out exactly why it happened...

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
       navigationVC?.navigationBar.sizeToFit()
 }
```